# How to connect Android emulator from pc to test socket listener?

Tags: android, sockets, android-emulator, serversocket

I have written a socket listener program for Android. In my program, I create a ServerSocket in port 1234. 
However, I don't know how to test it from my pc to emulator.
I try change proxy to 10.0.2.2 port 1234 but it not work.
Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could use ssh reverse tunneling to solve your problem. I haven't tried it to solve problem like yours, but here's the steps to do it:

- if your PC doesn't have a SSH Server running already, install it. It should be easy for Linux-based OS, not so easy for Windows but do-able. Cygwin will do, since I use that myself. Google will help you with this task.
- Install a SSH client App in your android emulator/device. I recommend [Terminal IDE](http://code.google.com/p/terminal-ide/downloads/list). Make sure you can PING your PC from the emulator/device. Try to PING it from Terminal IDE.
- run this command on Terminal IDE:

  ssh [your pc ssh user]@[your pc ip] -o "GatewayPorts yes" -R [SOME_PORT]:localhost:1234

If all goes smoothly, connection to localhost with port [SOME_PORT] (the same port for command above) will actually connect to your emulator/device port 1234.